# I'm going nuts with Heroku session management issues

Tags: python, session, heroku

I have a chatbot app at Heroku. Works fine in local but I get session errors in Heroku. The main issue is that sessions are getting crazy. I keep getting 404 errors.

My code to manage sessions :

```
class SessionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_threads = {}
        self.user_assistant_ids = {}
        self.thread_to_sid = {}
        self.user_ids = {}

    async def create_thread_for_sid(self, sid, assistant_id, user_id):
        try:
            loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
            # Assuming client.beta.threads.create returns a Thread-like object
            thread = await loop.run_in_executor(None, client.beta.threads.create)
            # Access the 'id' attribute of the thread object (adjust according to the actual attribute name)
            self.user_threads[sid] = thread.id if hasattr(thread, 'id') else None
            self.user_assistant_ids[sid] = assistant_id
            self.user_ids[sid] = user_id 
            self.thread_to_sid[thread.id if hasattr(thread, 'id') else None] = sid
            print(f"Thread created for new user: {thread.id if hasattr(thread, 'id') else 'Unknown ID'} with SID: {sid}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error creating thread for SID {sid}: {e}")

    def get_user_id(self, sid):
         return self.user_ids.get(sid)

    def get_thread_id(self, sid):
        return self.user_threads.get(sid)

    def get_sid_by_thread_id(self, thread_id):
        return self.thread_to_sid.get(thread_id)

    def get_assistant_id(self, sid):
        return self.user_assistant_ids.get(sid)

    def remove_session(self, sid):
        thread_id = self.user_threads.pop(sid, None)
        self.user_assistant_ids.pop(sid, None)
        if thread_id:
            self.thread_to_sid.pop(thread_id, None)
        # print(f"Session data removed for SID: {sid}")
```

I keep getting 404 erros

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. _Specifically,_ what does "I get session errors" mean? What does that have to do with 404s?

Comment: Also, you're just showing a class. What's the context here? Are you using Django, or another framework?

Comment: I'm using Quart. The context is sessions getting lost in Heroku. In the console it shows refused requests due to inexisting sessions. I assume that is because not always you will hit back the same instance at Heroku, and the session is not sticking. I tryed to put togueter a database session management but got too much erros.

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question. And if there's a tag for Quart, please add it. I'm not familiar with it, but... are you currently managing sessions in memory? You'll need to switch to a database or something. "I tryed to put togueter a database session management but got too much erros"—please show your attempt and include the errors.